# Ordenar registros do banco de dados em VARCHAR com ponto e vírgula

Tags: mysql

Como posso ordenar registros do bancos de dados gravados como ***VARCHAR***. Tentei sem sucesso o código abaixo. Como posso formatar para obter a ordem esperada?

```
SELECT *, CAST(representantes_vendas.valor AS INT)  FROM representantes_vendas
INNER JOIN representantes ON representantes_vendas.codigo_repre = representantes.codigo  
ORDER BY  representantes_vendas.valor DESC 


//Resultado Obtido
2017    99.948,54
2017    99,27
2017    91,10
2017    97.757,23


//Resultado esperado
2017    99.948,54
2017    97.757,23
2017    99,27
2017    91,10
```

Comment: Você pode converter para número (*float* ou *decimal* por exemplo) para ordenar. Para isso pode usar `cast` ou `convert`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html
Agora por que usar um campo `varchar` para guardar um valor numérico?

Comment: Vou verificar a possibilidade de alterar o campo para float.

Comment: Leia esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288357/como-fazer-a-soma-dos-valores-de-uma-coluna-somando-tamb%C3%A9m-os-decimais-no-php?noredirect=1#comment588048_288357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ordenação esperada for pelo valor numérico, você pode fazer a conversão apenas no `ORDER BY`. Exemplo:

```
SELECT *, CAST(representantes_vendas.valor AS INT)  FROM representantes_vendas
INNER JOIN representantes ON representantes_vendas.codigo_repre = representantes.codigo  
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(x.valor, ".", ""), ",", ".") AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) DESC
```

Comment: Para o campo definido como VARCHAR essa foi a solução, porém atualizei o campo para decimal(10,2) como orientado por Ricardo Pontual, atualizei os valores e apenas ordenei normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que sua notação é a brasileira que o ponto seria apenas para formatação, você pode removê-lo na ordenação:

```
SELECT *, CAST(representantes_vendas.valor AS INT)  FROM representantes_vendas
INNER JOIN representantes ON representantes_vendas.codigo_repre = representantes.codigo  
ORDER BY replace(representantes_vendas.valor, '.','') DESC
```